# Ubuntu Bootchart - How do I actually interpret this chart?

Tags: boot, optimization

I'd like to start obsessing over optimizing my Ubuntu boot time, but I've searched online for multiple days—and only have a vaguely more coherent idea of what I'm looking at.

Here's my [bootchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4rfR.png). I have noticed, looking at the bootchart of more optimized systems, that there are consistently large chunks of CPU usage in the first chart. I, on the other hand, have small blue spikes that are always overtaken by I/O Wait.

In the 2nd chart, I notice that the Disk Utilization is always at (what seems to be) its max. Does this mean that things are utilizing the disk inefficiently?

In which case, I think I'd like to maximize for CPU usage and minimize for disk utilization. I do not know how to do this, nor do I know if my interpretation of this chart is correct.

Could someone shed some light here? Other threads (on multiple sites) aren't very helpful with this magic.